# How can I tell when HttpClient.execute() is finished fetching all content in a large request?

Tags: java, android, network-programming, httpclient, http-get

I'm working with this issue on Android but it's not an Android-specific problem.

Using org.apache.http.client.HttpClient, I can make a request to a URL of size 1kb and the entire response is contained within HttpResponse:

```java
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://10.16.83.67/1kb.log");
HttpResponse response = null;
BufferedReader rd = null;

response = client.execute(request);
```

I can then get the HttpEntity from the response:

```java
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
```

And then, with BufferedReader...

```java
while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
 // ... parse or whatever
}
```

I'm watching WireShark and I see one transmit in each direction for the above code: the request for the log file, and then the entire log is delivered in the response.

However, if I request something larger, say, my 1MB log file, I see something very different.  **The data is chunked into frames and then streamed over the wire within the `rd.readLine()` loop.**

[image]

It seems the first kb or so is included in the initial response.  But then as `readLine()` runs, it makes additional requests to the server and the data is streamed to the socket.  If the network connection is interrupted, I get an IO error.  For large requests, `entity.isStreaming()` is `true`.

This is an asynchronous call (mandatory on Android, since network calls cannot be made on the UI thread) but I don't want to continue until I'm sure that I'm done receiving all of the data from this request.  Simply waiting an amount of time and then continuing and hoping for the best is, unfortunately, not an option.

My question is this: do my `HttpClient`, `HttpGet`, `HttpResponse`, or `HttpEntity` objects ever know when they are done receiving data from this request?  Or do I have to rely on BufferedReader to know when the stream is closed?

Comment: if it is streaming, that's the point, not to wait for the whole data to be received. Also, I don't see why you don't want to start reading before having received everything?

Comment: It's not that I need to wait for it to finish before I start working reading.  I just want to know 100% for sure when it's done, preferably by observing one of the objects I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you making use of AsyncTask? Otherwise you could go for this

```
 private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {}
```

// do all the http requests in the method above

```
 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("I pop up when all the code in the DoInbackground is finished");
 }
```

}

Comment: I like this idea.  If I only put the execute() in AsyncTask, it will not work.  But if I move all of the stream reads to doInBackground() method and then finish after the stream is done being read, it seems like it will do what I need.  Let me try it out.

Answer (score 1):

What httpclient are you useing? you may want to evaluate that.

There are good , httpclient  libs that allowing using stuff like [this](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/ChunkedInputStream.html)

Note this example from 3X. I use 4X and dont have any chunked response code to post.

If you want to look for new options, you might check [here](https://code.google.com/p/httpclientandroidlib/)

Comment: I'm using 3.1... I'll take a look at the chunking code.  It's interesting but I'm not sure it's what I'm looking for.  Thanks for the links.